# Mass translate taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have around 400 taxonomy terms; very complicated hierarchical stuff.

I wonder if anyone knows about a plugin (taxonomy manager style) that can help me do it without having to dive into taxonomy and translated one by one.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

[Translation Table](http://drupal.org/project/translation_table):

> This module presents your taxonomy terms or menu items in a table, and
>   each language has a corresponding column. Just fill out the
>   translations and click Save.